# Semantic error while running chandy mishra haas algorithm

Tags: c++

I wrote a `C++` program to implement `ChandyHaasMishra` algorithm in OR model in `eclipse for CDT (C/C++)`.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <vector>
# include <string>
# include <queue>

using namespace std;

void engage_query(vector<vector<int> > graph, int init, int dest);

void disp_graph(vector<vector<int> > mat);

void reply_query(vector<vector<int> > graph, int init, int dest);

int no_of_process;
vector<bool> wait_msg;
vector<int> msg_count;

int no_of_deadlocks = 0;
int no_of_knots = 0;

bool deadlock_flag = 0;

int main() {

    int probe_pid;

    int sites = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of sites (Minimum value greater than 1):" << endl;
    cin >> sites;

    for (int i = 0; i < sites; i++) {
        int temp;
        cout << "Enter number of processes for site" << (i+1) << ": (Minimum value greater than 1)";
        cin >> temp;
        no_of_process += temp;
    }

    cout << "Total number of sites = " << sites <<"; Total number of processes = " << no_of_process;

    if (no_of_process > 1) {
        cout << "Enter the wait graph for processes; Enter 1 if the process is dependent and 0 if not." << endl;

        vector<vector<int> > wait_graph(no_of_process);
        wait_msg.assign(no_of_process, false);
        msg_count.assign(no_of_process, 0);

        for (int from = 0; from < no_of_process; from++) {
            for (int to = 0; to < no_of_process; to++) {
                int temp;
                cout << "From Process "<< (from+1) <<" to : "<<(to+1)<<"(1/0) :";
                cin >> temp;
                wait_graph.at(from).push_back(temp);
            }
        }

        cout << endl;

        cout << "The wait-for graph is: " << endl;
        disp_graph(wait_graph);
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Enter the process initiating the probe (Between 1 and no_of_process): " << endl;
        cin >> probe_pid;
        cout << endl;
        probe_pid = probe_pid + 1;

        cout << "Initiating probe..."<<endl<<endl;
        cout << "DIRECTION \t PROBE \t MESSAGES \t WAIT_FLAG"<<endl;

        for (int col = 0; col < no_of_process; col++) {
            if (wait_graph.at(probe_pid).at(col) == 1) {
                cout << " S" << (probe_pid + 1) << " --> S" << (col + 1) << "     (" << (probe_pid + 1) << "," << (probe_pid + 1) << "," << (col + 1) << ")" << " , \t"<< wait_msg[probe_pid]<<" , \t"<<msg_count[probe_pid]<<endl;
                engage_query(wait_graph, probe_pid, col);
            }
        }

        cout<<"Number of deadlocks detected:"<<no_of_deadlocks<<endl;
        //Start the reverse process and try to reach the start node now.
        cout<<"Printing wait message array"<<endl;
        for(int m = 0; m<msg_count.size(); m++) {
            cout<<msg_count.at(m)<<endl;
        }

        if(no_of_deadlocks >= 2 ) {
            cout<<"\n Detecting knot ....................................."<<endl;
            vector<vector<int> > wait_graph_copy(wait_graph);
            for (int col = no_of_process; col > 0; col--) {
                if (wait_graph.at(col-1).at(probe_pid) == 1) {
                    cout << " S" << (probe_pid + 1) << " --> S" << (col) << "     (" << (probe_pid + 1) << "," << (probe_pid + 1) << "," << (col) << ")" <<" , \t"<< wait_msg[probe_pid]<<" , \t"<<msg_count[probe_pid]<<endl;
                    reply_query(wait_graph_copy, probe_pid, (col-1));
                }
            }
        }

        cout<<"Number of knots detected:"<<no_of_knots<<endl;
        if(no_of_deadlocks == no_of_knots) {
            cout << "Equal number of Deadlock and Knot detected. \n All sent messages were received. \nHence the Chandy-Misra-Hass OR detected is validated." << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Deadlock detection not possible. No process running in the system" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void display_graph(vector<vector<int> > wait_graph) {
    int n = wait_graph.at(0).size();
    int m = wait_graph.size();

    //Top Column
    cout << "\t";
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cout << "S" << (j + 1) << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    //Side column and values
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        cout << "S" << (i + 1) << "\t";
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << wait_graph.at(i).at(j) << "\t";
            if (wait_graph.at(i).at(j) ==1)
            {
                msg_count[i] += 1;
                wait_msg[i] = true;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void engaging_query(vector<std::vector<int> > &graph, int init, int dest) {
    int end = no_of_process;
    for (int col = 0; col < end; col++)
    {
        if (graph[dest][col] == 1)
        {
            if (init == col)
            {
                cout << " S" << (dest + 1) << " --> S" << (col + 1) <<"     (" << (init + 1) << "," << (dest + 1) << "," << (col + 1) << ")" << " --------> DEADLOCK DETECTED HERE" << endl;
                deadlock_flag = 1;
                no_of_deadlocks += 1;
                break;
            }

            cout << " S" << (dest + 1) << " --> S" << (col + 1) << "     (" << (init + 1) << "," << (dest + 1) << "," << (col + 1) << ")" << " ,\t "<< wait_msg[dest]<<" ,\t "<<msg_count[dest]<<endl;
            engaging_query(graph, init, col);
        }
    }
}

void reply_query(vector<std::vector<int> > &graph, int init, int dest)
{
    int end = no_of_process;
    for (int col = (end-1); col >= 0 ; --col)
    {
            //cout<<"\tdetectKnot() -- init="<<(init+1)<<" dest="<<(dest+1)<<" .col"<<(col+1)<<endl;
        if (graph[col][dest] == 1)
        {
            //cout<<"**dest:"<<dest<<" ,wait_msg_no:"<<wait_msg[dest]<<" ,msg_count:"<<msg_count[dest]<<endl;
            if (msg_count[dest] != 0) { msg_count[dest] -= 1; }
            if (msg_count[dest] == 0) { wait_msg[dest] = false; }
            if (init == col)
            {
                cout << " S" << (dest + 1) << " --> S" << (col+1) <<"     (" << (init + 1) << "," << (dest + 1) << "," << (col+1) << ")" << " --------> KNOT DETECTED HERE" << endl;
                no_of_knots += 1;
                if(wait_msg[dest] == false && msg_count[dest] == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (msg_count[dest] == 0 && wait_msg[dest] == false) {
                   graph[col][dest] = 0;
            }

            cout << " S" << (dest + 1) << " --> S" << (col + 1) << "     (" << (init + 1) << "," << (dest + 1) << "," << (col+1) << ")" <<" , \t"<< wait_msg[dest]<<" , \t"<<msg_count[dest]<<endl;
            reply_query(graph, init, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get below error:
[image: error]
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your forward declaration does not match the actual function definition:

```
void reply_query(vector<vector<int> > graph, int init, int dest);
...
void reply_query(vector<std::vector<int> > &graph, int init, int dest)
```

It causes the compiler to think there are two distinct overloads, and when you call `reply_query()` both are viable candidates, so it cannot decide which one to use.

The simplest solution is to avoid forward declarations where possible, by reordering the functions so that `reply_query()` comes before `main()`.

Comment: Oh... I hadn't considered those forward declarations. Thank you...